# How to convert an HTMLLIElement to an array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have this code :

```
const listItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li'));
listItems.splice(0, 0, '');
```

It gives me an error 
***Argument of type '""' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLLIElement'.(2345)***

I am already using Array.from, why doesn't Typescript understand that this is an array and not an HTMLLIElement

Playground : 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=2&ssc=28&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2gSSgUwLYRgXhgQQCdCBDATwDoAzQkDACgBMRgBXDNMKCgR1bUJkAymjhpgUEIXxw49AOSJ5ASmUBuAFCIU6LBQgAHRMDT0ADABoYlmPJVqgA

Comment: So are you trying to 1) query the `<li>` elements in the documents, 2) then extract the text from each element and put that into an array, 3) then finally trying to insert an item at index `0`? If so, it seems you haven't done step #2 to extract `textContent` so `listItems` is still an array of html elements and you will not be able to modify that array with non html element values.

Comment: This is just a reduced test to show the error, I just don't understand why typescript does not see this as an array. Don't try to understand the logic behind it, more as to how I can tell typescript this is an array

Comment: It does it see it as an array, the error is saying, you cannot adding an item of type `string` to an array of type `HTMLLIElement`. `''` in the third argument of `splice` being the `string` in question. You need to make the array and array of `string` if you want to splice a `string` into it.

Comment: Ok well do you have a solution so it doesn't see it as an array instead an array? Because I convert it to an array with Array.from

Comment: Yes, I added an answer. Using `Array.prototype.map` or similar, create an array targeting the respective property of each `<li>` element. Then you can splice onto that new `string[]` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to add value of type `string` (based on the third argument of your `Array.prototype.splice` operation) to an array of not type `string[]`. `listItems` is an array of `HTMLLIElement`, it's just not array of `string`. If you were splicing a newly created `<li>` element to that array, you would not have this error.

If you are trying to create and modify an array of type `string[]` consisting of the `textContent` of each queried `<li>` element you can instead try creating a new array of `string[]` targeting the respective property of each `<li>` element such as `textContent`:

```
// query `<li>` elements and create an array of html elements
const listItems: HTMLLIElement[] = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li'));
// create array of `string[]` of the text content of each element
const values: (string | null)[] = listItems.map(el => el.textContent);
// execute splice on the new `string[]` array
values.splice(0, 0, '');
```